# Ruby format DateTimeParameter in where query

Tags: ruby, date, datetime, where-clause

I want to do a query like this:

```
bookings = Booking.where(user_id: @current_user.id, start_at: date.to_datetime)
```

The problem in this case is, that I just get results in bookings which match a timestamp `00:00:00` which is quite logical.

Is there a possibility to format the `start_at` parameter in the query to date, so that I just compare two dates and not datetimes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try convert your datetime field to date via SQL:

```
bookings = Booking.where(user_id: @current_user.id)
                  .where("DATE(start_at) = ?", date)
```

DATE() extracts the date part of a datetime expression.

Note: it does not works in PotsgreSQL

Or:

```
bookings = Booking.where(user_id: @current_user.id,
                         created_at: date.beginning_of_day..date.end_of_day)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
bookings = Booking.where(user_id: @current_user.id, start_at: start_date..end_date)
```

or

```
bookings = Booking.where(user_id: @current_user.id)
                  .where('start_at > ? AND start_at < ?', start_date, end_date)
```

where start_date and end_date are the two dates you wish to check between.